# Support for author does not show author column in post table in dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),`
```

This argument should display author column on wordpress dashboard's post table, but it does not in "listing" custom post type in Elegant theme's "Explorable".

Any idea?

Update: I think this part of the code is restricting author from the post table, how could I add author to it:

```
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-listing_columns', 'et_listing_edit_columns' );
function et_listing_edit_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb'                    => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title'                 => __( 'Title', 'Explorable' ),
        'et_listing_type'       => __( 'Type', 'Explorable' ),
        'et_listing_location'   => __( 'Location', 'Explorable' ),
    );

    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'et_listing_custom_columns' );
function et_listing_custom_columns( $column ) {
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom();

    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'et_listing_type' :
            $et_listing_types = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'listing_type' );

            if ( !empty( $et_listing_types ) ) {
                $out = array();
                foreach ( $et_listing_types as $et_listing_type ) {
                    $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                        esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => 'listing', 'listing_type' => $et_listing_type->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
                        esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $et_listing_type->name, $et_listing_type->term_id, 'listing_type', 'display' ) )
                    );
                }

                echo join( ', ', $out );
            } else {
                _e( 'None', 'Explorable' );
            }

            break;
        case 'et_listing_location' :

            $et_listing_locations = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'listing_location' );

            if ( !empty( $et_listing_locations ) ) {
                $out = array();
                foreach ( $et_listing_locations as $et_listing_location ) {
                    $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                        esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => 'listing', 'listing_location' => $et_listing_location->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
                        esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $et_listing_location->name, $et_listing_location->term_id, 'listing_location', 'display' ) )
                    );
                }

                echo join( ', ', $out );
            } else {
                _e( 'None', 'Explorable' );
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if it's not hidden by default within the Screen Options pane in the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: Checked, Author is not an option on the selection list, only two associate taxonomy: type and location.

Comment: Can you please post the part of code in which you're calling `register_post_type()`?

Comment: updated the post for clarification.

Comment: By default `Author` is a valid column, but your `et_listing_edit_columns()` function removes all columns and replaces them with 4 custom ones.

Comment: Would it be possible to add Author alongside these columns?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing all the columns just add and remove the columns that you want.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-listing_columns', 'et_listing_edit_columns' );
function et_listing_edit_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns['et_listing_type'] = __( 'Type', 'Explorable' );
    $columns['et_listing_location'] = __( 'Location', 'Explorable' );

    // You can remove columns with unset()
    return $columns;
}
```